# Spotify Native crashing on start

Tags: 11.04, spotify

Since an update about 8 weeks ago, Spotify native will no longer start.  Below is the terminal output:

```
tom@blacknight:~$ spotify
17:31:59.810 I [breakpad.cpp:36] Registered Breakpad for product: spotify

17:31:59.879 I [translate.cpp:117] Reloading all languages
17:31:59.889 I [fsevents:403] starting polling thread
17:31:59.949 I [breakpad.cpp:94] Searching for crashdumps: /home/tom/.cache/spotify/*.dmp

17:32:00.923 I [ap:1374] Connecting to AP B1.spotify.com:4070
17:32:01.058 I [ap:924] Connected to AP: 78.31.8.42:4070
QDBusArgument: write from a read-only object
17:32:01.413 I [upnp:517] 192.168.1.1: got external ip 0x51663686
17:32:01.423 I [upnp:465] 192.168.1.1: mapping add ok
17:32:01.429 I [upnp:491] 192.168.1.1: Port 21238 mapped OK
Segmentation fault
tom@blacknight:~$
```

Does anyone know of a solution?  There's been a couple of updates since but neither have fixed this :(

Ubuntu 11.04 x64, classic desktop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately for those of you who still have this issue, I don't have an answer, however fortunately for myself, the issue resolved itself after the latest update (which removed the gnome support package).  It's even working on Ubuntu 11.10!

The clearing the cache, suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55680/spotify-native-crashing-on-start/63522#63522) would make the login screen appear (I assume any user saved information was being cleared), however logging in again would cause it to crash.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to clean the cache?. I find that sometimes, after an update, Spotify won't work unless you clear it:

```
rm -Rf ~/.cache/spotify
```

I hope that it helps as it is a blind shot.

Comment: I had the same issue on 12.04 with the up-to-date spotify. I solved it by removing:
.cache/spotify
.config/spotify
and the spotify app from my facebook account Thanks for all the hints!

Answer (score 1):

You can debug it with strace and check what is happening just before the segfault :

```
strace -e open spotify
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem and it seems to be a problem with the facebook connection module in newer versions of the Spotify for Linux binary.

I don't yet know what causes it, but a workaround until Spotify corrects this bug is to log out facebook from your Spotify account using a Windows or Mac computer, or perhaps using wine in Linux, but this I've not tried myself. This way the client skips the step of gathering information from facebook, and should start as usual without any crashes.

Unfortunately the Spotify for Linux binary is still a preview version, so it should not be too big a suprise that it sometimes breaks.